# jQuery Ajax GET request not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call an AJAX query and have had lots of trouble recently.
Im trying to call a `api` that I have custom made myself, it displays this when the url `api/reverse/test` - `tset` (is just uses a php function to reverse the text given in the slug3.

That function works fine, just wanted to give some back on what gets requested.

**reverse.php** - HTML File

```
<textarea id="input"></textarea>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

**index.js** - All of my jQuery and AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $input = $('#input');
  var $output = $('#output');

  $input.on('keyup', function(){
    var text = $input.val();
    var url = 'http://coder.jekoder.com/api/?area=reverse&text='+text;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) { var output = data; },
        error: alert('fail')
  }) // End of AJAX

  $output.html = output;
 });
});
```

**api.php** - PHP file being called

```
<?php
  $area = $_GET['area'];

  if ($area == 'reverse') {
    if (isset($_GET['text']) ) $text = $_GET['text'];
      else $text = 'Hello';

    echo strrev($text);
  }
```

It's then supposed to take the `output` variable and display that in a div but that's not the main thing that matters.

**error removed - was trying to see if it fixed it**

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: @JayBlanchard There is no error given in the browser developer tools. The jQuery library is given and I'm running this on a Linux server. - Paid hosting.

Comment: Should'nt `var text = $('#input')` be `var text = $('#input').val()?`

Comment: `It's then supposed to take the output variable and display that in a div`  But could you provide all relevant code you are using, because this is obviously not the one you have posted. BTW, this warning message has nothing to do with your ajax request code you have posted (if you don't set ajax globally to synch). It could be because you are trying to append a script tag using `html()` method. Anyway, this is a warning, not an error

Comment: The error you're seeing is because you've used `async: false` in at least one of your `$.ajax()` requests

Comment: Just edited the question @A.Wolff

Answer (score 1):

There are several issue I found:

Jquery:

```
       var text =  $('#input').val(); // if you are getting value from any inputbox - get value using .val() function
        var url = 'http://localhost/test.php?data='+text; // pass data like this ?data='+text
        // AJAX START
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: url,
          dataType: 'text',
          async: true,
          success: function(data) { var output = data;  alert(output)},
          error: function(data) { alert('fail') }
        });
```

In php you ca get data like this:

```
echo $_GET['data'];
exit;
```

Comment: Right, good points that need to be fixed but how would it explain console warning regarding synchronous request?

Comment: My site does run slugs - And I added this code and changed the slugs around and it still didn't manage to work, I still get the error

Comment: set async: true in ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Scope of variable `output` is within the success call and you are using it outside the ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var $input = $('#input');
    var $output = $('#output');

    $input.on('keyup', function()
    {
         var text = $input.val();
         var url = 'http://coder.jekoder.com/api/?area=reverse&text='+text;
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) { var output = data; $output.html = output;},
            error: alert('fail')
       }) // End of AJAX


    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and other stuff and the call still seems to not want to work, really weord...

Comment: try after remove `dataType: 'text',`